# Access Spacy's trained model/folder in google cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, spacy

I was deploying a python application which uses Spacy's custom trained model on GAE. I have also uploaded model folder in Google Cloud Storage but am facing issues in getting only folder from storage bucket and using that to load in spacy.

Right now, if I am trying to get a blob, I can get only one file, not a folder.

Please help me.

FYI, Spacy's custom trained and saved model is a folder that contains multiple files.
Thanks

**EDIT 1 :**

This is the directory structure of saved model

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage doesn't have folders in the reality, what you see as folders are just a representation, you can see a more detailed explanation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork).

What you have to do is to fetch all the files inside of a "folder" recursively. i.e.:

```
import sys
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage.blob import Blob


client = storage.Client()
for blob in client.list_blobs('mybucket', prefix='sofolder'):
    blobname = blob.name
    blobstring = str(blobname)
    blobcleaname = blobstring.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    if not blobstring.endswith('/'):
        blob.download_to_filename('./' + str(blobcleaname))
        print(blobstring)
```

---

Update 1:

So I did a quick reproduction of your use case by just printing to console the name of my bucket. I have a structure similar to yours:

```
bucketname
    -filexxx 
    -folderyyy
    -sofolder <--- the folder i'm interested in
      -file1.png
      -folder_a
        -fileinfolder_a.png
      -folder_b
        -fileinfolder_b.png
      -folder_c
        -fileinfolder_c.png
```

and by runnning this:

```
import sys
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage.blob import Blob

client = storage.Client()
for blob in client.list_blobs('bucketname', prefix='sofolder'):
    blobname = blob.name
    blobstring = str(blobname)
    if not blobstring.endswith('/'):
        print(blobstring)
```

I'm getting this output:

```
sofolder/
sofolder/file1.png
sofolder/folder_a/fileinfolder_a.png
sofolder/folder_b/fileinfolder_b.png
sofolder/folder_c/fileinfolder_c.png
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris32 but this will mess up the code as there are 4 subdirectories and then 16 files. I have updated question with directory structure. Please have a look

Comment: are those the only files in /model_output? or you have more files in that folder that you don't want to retrieve?

Comment: There are these only

Comment: I updated my answer. In the first part I updated my code with a functional sample to download the files recursively, in the second part I described how I listed only the files inside my desired folder. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey! if this answer helped you please don't forget to approve and upvote, so this can help other users with similar issues! otherwise let me know what is missing

Comment: I won't forget that. Don't worry. I am yet to come back to this issue as i am stuck in others. Thanks for the answer though. @Chris32